# Using an Activity to Launch Either Login or Main Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application which currently launches a simple LaunchActivity upon starting. Within this activity, there is a conditional in onCreate() to check for the existence of session data. If no session data exists, it starts the LoginActivity. Otherwise, it starts the MainActivity. In both cases, it finishes the LaunchActivity before starting either activity.

Using this approach, there is a brief flicker of the LaunchActivity before the start of either other activity. If this is an appropriate approach, what can be done to eliminate the flicker?

Is there another approach to this behavior which does not involve a LaunchActivity?

Comment: Another approach would be to launch the Login Activity first and check if the session data exist. If existing, terminate the LoginActivity and start the MainActivity. But I don't know if it helps with the flickering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it finishes the LaunchActivity before starting either activity.

This sounds like you are destroying your Activity, then launching a new one. What you can do instead is open the new `Activity` using `Intent` then finish the launch Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);//or LoginActivity.class
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Additionally, you can specify in your manifest that you do not want the launch activity to be included in the Back Stack. This will make it so that when the back button is pressed to exit the main or login activities, the launch activity will not be shown.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```